# Get out of memory with dataSet.GetXml()

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I've got error "System.OutOfMemoryException" if dataSet is too large and the memory is enough.
The size of file "file1.xml" is about 36 MB.

What is the way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

```
private XPathDocument GetXML(DataSet ds)
    {
        ds.WriteXml("file1.xml");
        ds.WriteXmlSchema("file1.xsd");

        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(ds.GetXml()));

        return doc;
    }
```

Comment: Is it throwing in ds.GetXml or the StringReader constructor?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach it might be a bit less sensitive.

```
private XPathDocument GetXML(DataSet ds)
{
    ds.WriteXml("file1.xml");
    ds.WriteXmlSchema("file1.xsd");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("file1.xml");

    return new XPathDocument(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using dataset.ReadXml("MyFilename");

This has worked for me. I was able to read a file for 250 MB on a machine which has 4GB RAM.

Edit: Try on a machine which has more RAM.

HTH